# Change color of popup that appears after flagging Area 51 proposal

Tags: feature-request, flags, area-51

When you flag an Area 51 propsal, you get a red popup "Thanks! We'll look at it! (click this box to dismiss)". The same when you vote to close a proposed question: you get a red popup. However, that red color does me think that there is something wrong with my flag/close vote. So I suggest to change the color of this popup into blue.

Worth to mention such thing already exists on other sites e.g. Stack Overflow delete vote:

> [image]

Comment: Said well, it should not be red!

Comment: I think it should be brown. (Don't get it, check the Tavern)